No tests shown in Visual Studio Code Test Panel
I have tests in my VS Code workspace but the testing panel does not find any. It simply says "No test have been found in this work space yet".
However there are definitely tests present because dotnet test TestProject1.sln works, it finds one test and executes it.
VS Code Version 1.95.3
C# Dev Kit Extension Version 1.13.9
I created a simple solution just to eliminate any code or projects that could cause this issue but it still did not display any tests
namespace TestProject1;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}

The Test Explorer showing no tests found
Result of dotnet test
Finally I tried installing another extension .NET Core Test Explorer and this extension does find the test
.NET Core Test Explorer Extension does work
Tried rebuilding and restarting VS Code, to no avail
I tried installing on another old windows laptop I had and I opened the same workspace. Initially I had the same problem, no tests shown but then suddenly it worked. The tests were discovered in test explorer. I do not know why it works on this laptop and not on my main laptop.
Update
I got very little answers. I discovered the issue related to C# Dev Kit after making more tests. The problem seems to have been introduced in version 1.10.16 of the C# Dev extension. Version before that work fine, and all subsequent version fail to discover any tests. Same workspace.
Git Hub Issue

Did you follow Getting started with testing in VS Code, and Testing ?   It seems to work for /me, see: https://i.sstatic.net/JfcZ8nG2.png

Yes I did read this but it does not mention anything that would seem to resolve my issue. What version of VS Code, and C# Dev Kit extension are you using?

ms-dotnettools.csdevkit@1.13.9;  code --version: 1.95.3 windows 11, and this Dotnet Test Explorer

I thought the C# Dev Kit was enough for the tests to be discovered. I installed Dotnet Test explorer to see if it worked (it did), but my understanding is that the tests should be discovered with only C# Dev Kit extension.

see: Testing with C# Dev Kit (from the bottom link here). There is explained what is covered, and also Test Explorer is mentioned.

If your projects are part of a solution, try building the entire solution. If they are not, ensure that each project is built individually.
You can build the solution using the following command:
dotnet build SLN_FILE_LOCATION /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"

This worked for me when using only the C# DevKit extension in VS Code.

Thanks for suggestion. I tried building solution and projects but no luck, the tests are still no shown.
